# How to upload a file in device on phonegap application

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

Hi i am working on phonegap application and i want to upload a audio file i am using  but it's working in browser but not working in device so can u help me to upload and get the path of the file.

example

```
<input type="file"/>
<button id="btn">click</button>

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#btn").click(function(){
alert($("input").val());
})
});
```

this example is not work on device but its work on the browser so please tell me the way to upload file in device.

Comment: Check this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileUploadOptions)

Comment: hey mate i know about this link but in my device <input type="file"> is not working so how can i get the the path of file.

Comment: When you say work in browser, you mean in browser on a computer? (and not in browser in device) You should specify on which device OS/version you have your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot browse the SDcard directly in phonegGap. By using file explorer plugins,You would upload a file in apps & you can also get a path using this.
[mobile-file-explorer-with-phonegapcordova-and-jquery-mobile-part](http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/mobile-file-explorer-with-phonegapcordova-and-jquery-mobile-part-1/)

[image: plugins ScreenShot][image: plugins ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can open an sdcard and select a file to upload using phonegap.However here is a simple way to get all the files in an folder and upload it to the server.You can customize it to your requirement and use it ,I hope it helps.

```
    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {


 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSys = fileSystem;
    }
    , fsFail);

fileSys.root.getDirectory("myFolder/", {create: true, exclusive: false},  
    function(parent) {
        folder=parent;
    }
    , dirFail);

    //Creating a reader
    var directoryReader = folder.createReader();
    // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
    directoryReader.readEntries(ReaderSucces,readerFail);   

function ReaderSucces(entries){

    var i,len;
    len = entries.length;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (entries[i].isDirectory) {
             var directoryReaderIn = entries[i].createReader();
            directoryReaderIn.readEntries(ReaderSucces,readingFail); 
        }
         if(entries[i].isFile==true)
        {
        entries[i].file(uploadFile, readingFail);
        }
    }
}

var fsFail = function(error) {
        alert("failed with error code: " + error.code);
};                  
var dirFail = function(error) {
    alert("Directory error code: " + error.code);
};
var readerFail = function(error) {
    alert("Reading Directory error code: " + error.code);
};          
var readingFail = function (error){
    console.log("Reading Files error code: "+error.code);
};

}


function uploadFile(file) {

var target="http://YOUR_IP/upload.php"; //the url to upload on server
var ft = new FileTransfer();
var path = file.fullPath; //"file://"+ 
var name = file.name;

var ft = new FileTransfer();

ft.upload(path, encodeURI(target), win, fail, { fileName: name, fileKey: "file", mimeType:"text/plain" });          
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

An API to read, write and navigate file system hierarchies is given in phonegap also.
You can use FileTransfer.upload() for this purpose. Take a look at this documentation
[Phonegap documentation for File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html)